# how to detach from a docker container

Tags: docker

This problem is quite similar like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19688314/1381490), but I am still having problems:

I run a container with:

```
docker run -d CONTAINER
```

then I attach to it with

```
docker attach NAME
```

but I cannot exit it, not with CTRL-C, nor with CTRL-P + CTRL-Q (like suggested in the similar question above)

I have to `kill -9 PID` to exit it...

What am I doing wrong?

### Info:

Docker version 0.6.7, build cb48ecc
Ubuntu 3.8.0-33-generic #48~precise1-Ubuntu

Comment: The question should simply be, "Why doesnt CTRL-P + CRTL-Q work as advertised?" Nowhere in the docs does it say that you have to be running in some magical proxy configuration to work properly.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

You should `attach` to the container using the `--sig-proxy=false` option like this:

```
docker attach --sig-proxy=false NAME
```

Then you can use `CTRL`+`C`to exit without stopping the container itself.

Comment: it not works in docker 1.0 env. @bibstha do you have any update.

Comment: doesn't really work in my system.
Solution with ^P^Q works perfectly though!

Comment: This does not work for OSx if you use Docker Quickstart Terminal.

Comment: `ctrl+p+q` works for me on OS/X. Detaches but leaves the container running.

Answer (score 86):

As [Jérôme Petazzoni mentioned in docker-user group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/docker-user/nWXAnyLP9-M/kbv-FZpF4rUJ):

```
Actually, you can SIGKILL the client, and reattach later.
However, this will disrupt stdin (the container will see EOF on stdin, and if it cares about stdin, e.g. if it's a shell, it will exit).

To recap:
docker run -t -i → can be detached with ^P^Q and reattached with docker attach
docker run -i → cannot be detached with ^P^Q; will disrupt stdin
docker run → cannot be detached with ^P^Q; can SIGKILL client; can reattach with docker attach
```

Answer (score 1):

Attaching with:

```
docker attach <container name>
```

allows me to detach with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> in Docker version 17.04

I know this is old, but since none of the methods shown above work for me, I thought I'd share.