# difference between docker attach and docker exec

Tags: docker, exec, docker-exec

Both will be able to execute commands in container.
Both could detach the container.

So what is the real difference between the `docker exec` and `docker attach` commands?

Answer (score 110, accepted):

2015: There was a [commit PR](https://github.com/docker/docker/commit/2f46ec60c012e94771698351515178fe9caea21a) which added to the doc:

> **Note:** This command (`attach`) is not for running a new process in a container.
> See: `docker exec`.

The answer to "[Docker. How to get bash\ssh inside ran container (`run -d`)?](https://askubuntu.com/a/507009/5470)" illustrates the difference:

> (docker >= 1.3) If we use [`docker attach`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/attach/), **we can use only one instance of shell** (See [Manuel Jordan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3665178/manuel-jordan)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77997774/6309) on that).
> So if we want to open a new terminal with new instance of container's shell, we just need to run [`docker exec`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/)
>
> if the docker container was started using `/bin/bash` command, you can access it using attach, if not then you need to *execute* the command to create a bash instance inside the container using `exec`.

As mentioned in [this issue](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/2855#issuecomment-57102647):

> - Attach isn't for running an extra thing in a container, it's for attaching to the running process.
> - "`docker exec`" is specifically for running new things in a already started container, be it a shell or some other process.

The same issue adds:

> While `attach` is not well named, particularly because of the LXC command `lxc-attach` (which is more akin `docker exec <container> /bin/sh`, but LXC specific), it does have a specific purpose of literally attaching you to the process Docker started.
> **Depending on what the process is, the behavior may be different**, for instance attaching to `/bin/bash` will give you a shell, but attaching to Redis-server will be like you'd just started Redis directly without daemonizing.

---

Update 2022: See more with "**[Containers 101: attach vs. exec - what's the difference?](https://iximiuz.com/en/posts/containers-101-attach-vs-exec/)**" (Dec. 2021) from [Ivan Velichko](https://twitter.com/iximiuz):

[image: https://iximiuz.com/containers-101-attach-vs-exec/docker-attach-2000-opt.png]

Extract:

> ### Difference between attach and logs
>
> On the diagram above, `docker attach` streams the container's logs back to the terminal.
> However, the `docker logs` command does a similar thing.
> So, what's the difference?
>
> The logs command provides various options to filter the logs while attach in that regard acts as a simple tail.
> But what's even more important is that the stream established by the logs command is always unidirectional and connected to the container's logs, not the container's stdio streams directly.
>
> The logs command simply streams the content of the container's logs back to your terminal, and that's it.
> So, regardless of how you created your container (interactive or non-interactive, controlled by a pseudo-terminal or not), you cannot accidentally impact the container while using the logs command.
>
> However, when attach is used:
>
> - If a container was created in the interactive mode (`-i`), everything you type in the terminal after attach-ing to the container will be sent to its stdin.
> - You can (intentionally or accidentally) send a signal to the container - [for instance, hitting ctrl+c on your end while attached sends `SIGINT` to the container](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49226544/6309).
>
> ### What does exec command do
>
> The exec command is actually a totally different story.
>
> In the case of attach, we were connecting our terminal to an existing container (read, process).
>
> However, the `exec` command <del>starts a totally new container!</del>
> In other words, `exec` is a form of the `run` command (which itself is just a shortcut for `create` + `start`).

[Bart](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1023850/bart) reminds us in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30960686/difference-between-docker-attach-and-docker-exec/30962120#comment126703209_30962120) that [`docker exec`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/) runs a new command in a *running* container. Not a "totally new one".

Comment: Good to know. However regarding your last bit on docker exec: `docker exec` does NOT start a (totally) new container. It runs a (new) command in the running container that you specify. As a `docker exec --help` tells you:

Usage:  docker exec [OPTIONS] CONTAINER COMMAND [ARG...]
Run a command in a running container [...]

Comment: @Bart Thank you, good point. I have edited the answer to make that clearer, and to include your comment for more visibility.

Comment: Is interesting that the `we can use only one instance of shell` part does not appear explicitly (or similarly) in the `attach` command. It in the official documentation

Comment: And again about `we can use only one instance of shell` it seems a contradiction against: `You can attach to the same contained process multiple times simultaneously, screen sharing style, or quickly view the progress of your detached process`. It is available at [What is Docker attach?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44347397/what-is-docker-attach)

Comment: @ManuelJordan Let me know if you find more on that, and do not hesitate to edit this 2015 answer accordingly.

Comment: Let me test it with the latest docker release and mostly according with the image type, because it affects "the behavior" of the `docker attach` command, it for example if the image itself is based the web server, database and linux types

Comment: @VonC I added the following answer to complement your current valuable answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/77997774/3665178

Answer (score 31):

When a container is started using /bin/bash then it becomes the containers **PID 1** and docker attach is used to get inside PID 1 of a container. So **docker attach < container-id >** will take you inside the bash terminal as it's PID 1 as we mentioned while starting the container. Exiting out from the container will stop the container.

Whereas in **docker exec** command you can specify which shell you want to enter into. It will not take you to PID 1 of the container. It will create a new process for bash.
**docker exec -it < container-id > bash**.
Exiting out from the container will not stop the container.

You can also use **nsenter** to enter inside containers.
**nsenter -m -u -n -p -i -t < pid of container >**
You can find PID of container using: docker inspect < container-id > | grep PID

**Note:** If you have started your container with -d flag then exiting out of container will not stop the container,whether you use attach or exec to get inside.

Comment: Interesting idea about using `nsenter`. Can you elaborate? Explaining the options would be in order. Why not enter all namespaces? Why these particular ones?

Answer (score 22):

As Michael Sun stated in his answer

> `docker exec` executes a new command / create a new process in the container’s environment, while `docker attach` just connects the standard input/output/error of the main process(with PID 1) inside the container to corresponding standard input/output/error of current terminal(the terminal you are using to run the command).

My answer will focus more on letting you validate the above statement and understand it more clearly.

Open up a terminal window and run the command `docker run -itd --name busybox busybox /bin/sh`. The command will pull the image `busybox` if not already present. It will then create a container with the name `busybox` using this image.

You can check the status of your container by running the command `docker ps -a | grep busybox`.

If you run `docker top busybox`, you should see an output something like this.

```
UID                 PID                 PPID                C                   STIME               TTY                 TIME                CMD
root                7469                7451                0                   11:40               pts/0               00:00:00            /bin/sh
```

Of course, the `PID`, `PPID` and other values will be different in your case. You can use other tools and utilities as well like `pstree`, `top`, `htop` to see the list of `PID` and `PPID`.

The `PID` and `PPID` means the process id and parent process id. The process started when we created and started our container with the command `/bin/sh`. Now, run the command `docker attach busybox`. This will attach the standard input/output/error stream of the container to your terminal.

After attaching the container, create a shell session by running the command `sh`. Press `CTRL-p CTRL-q` sequence. This will detach the terminal from the container and will keep the container running. If you'll now run `docker top busybox`, you should see two processes in the list.

```
UID                 PID                 PPID                C                   STIME               TTY                 TIME                CMD
root                7469                7451                0                   11:40               pts/0               00:00:00            /bin/sh
root                7737                7469                0                   11:43               pts/0               00:00:00            sh
```

But the `PPID` of the two processes will be different. In fact, the `PPID` of the second process will be the same as `PID` of the first one. The first process acts as the parent process for the shell session that we just created.

Now, run `docker exec -it busybox sh`. Once inside the container, check the list of running processes for the container `busybox` in another terminal window by running the command `docker top busybox`. You should see something like this

```
UID                 PID                 PPID                C                   STIME               TTY                 TIME                CMD
root                7469                7451                0                   11:40               pts/0               00:00:00            /bin/sh
root                7737                7469                0                   11:43               pts/0               00:00:00            sh
root                7880                7451                0                   11:45               pts/1               00:00:00            sh
```

The `PPID` of the first and third process will be the same, which confirms that `docker exec` creates a new process in the container's environment while `docker attach` just connects the standard input/output/error of the main process inside the container to corresponding standard input/output/error of current terminal.

Answer (score 6):

Docker exec executes a new command / create a new process in the container’s environment, while docker attach just connects the standard input/output/error of the main process(with PID 1) inside the container to corresponding standard input/output/error of current terminal(the terminal you are using to run the command).

A container is an isolated environment, with some processes running in the environment. Specifically, a container has its own file system space and PID space that are isolated from host and other containers. 
When the container is started using “docker run –it …”, the main process will have a pseudo-tty and STDIN kept open. 
When attached in the tty mode, you can detach from the container (and leave it running) using a configurable key sequence. The default sequence is CTRL-p CTRL-q.  You configure the key sequence using the --detach-keys option or a configuration file. 
You can reattach to a detached container with docker attach.

Docker exec just starts a new process, inside the container’s environment, that is, belongs to the PID space of the container.

For example, if you start your container using “docker run –dit XXX /bin/bash”,you can attach to the container(‘s main process) using two different terminals. While you are inputting in one terminal, you can see it appears in the other terminal, for both terminal are connected to same tty. 
Be careful that you are now in the main process of the container, if you type “exit”, you will exit the container(*so be careful, using detach-keys to detach*), and you will see both terminals exited. 
But if you run “docker exec –it XXX /bin/bash” in two terminals, you have started two new processes inside the container, and they are not related to each other and to the main process, and you can safely exit from them.

Answer (score 2):

To complement the valuable answer that currently indicates:

> we can use only **one instance** *of shell*

And in the following post (which is mentioned in a comment in the valid answer)

- [What is Docker attach?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44347397/what-is-docker-attach)

indicates:

> You can attach to the same contained process **multiple times simultaneously**, screen sharing style, or quickly view the progress of your detached process

At a first glance it seems a contradiction between them but after to did do some experiments both are correct according the perspective:

*If in the host* where docker is running was executed the `docker run --name <containername> -itd ubuntu` command and then:

- *if in the host* is opened for example **two** `tty` and is executed for each one the `docker attach <containername>` command then these two tty share the **same** output according if any of them is used - even for typing at realtime!. Therefore each one is reflected to the other as a mirror.
- *if in the host* is executed the `docker exec -it <containername>` command it opens the expected shell within the **same** container but isolated about the content/interaction against of the two others tty related with the `docker attach` command.

Now is very clear the difference between `attach` and `exec`.

Therefore the origin of the confusion is when in the host exists only two tty, one is for `docker attach` and the other for `docker exec`, therefore for this specific scenario *it seems* both are equals.

Comment: Looking good, thank you for the update. Upvoted, and referenced from [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30962120/6309).

Comment: @VonC Thanks! - now the idea is complete for the developers