# Access to a docker container on Heroku

Tags: heroku, docker

I am using [Heroku with Docker](https://blog.heroku.com/archives/2015/5/5/introducing_heroku_docker_release_build_deploy_heroku_apps_with_docker). I need to upload files in `/public/pictures` and I want to do it via sftp or scp. I tried to expose the port 22 and access to the container with this comment :

```
ssh app@application.herokuapp.com
```

It do nothing.

Is there a way to do it? Is there a better way?

Comment: In general you shouldn't use ssh to access your container. You can use `docker exec container /bin/bash` to access your container.

Answer (score 0):

As documented in "[If you run SSHD in your Docker containers, you're doing it wrong!](http://jpetazzo.github.io/2014/06/23/docker-ssh-considered-evil/)", most containers don't include `sshd`.

[`docker exec`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/) (as [I mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30962120/6309)) will open a new shell and allow you to access the container.