# Log doesn't save to file in docker environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, docker

In my production environment `production.rb`. I have configured my log will be saved to file:

```
  config.logger = Logger.new('log/production.log')
```

When I run locally (start server by using command line `rails s -e production`). everything works fine. But when I run on docker environment, I don't see `production.log` printed out.

Please help me about this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't see production.log printed out.

Where are you looking? On your host or in the docker container that you are running?

By default, the file will be created in your container filesystem.
If you want it directly visible from your host (which runs the docker daemon), you would need to [mount an host directory as a data volume](https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/#/mount-a-host-directory-as-a-data-volume) first.

```
docker run -d -P --name myapp -v /a/local/host/path:/path/to/log/in/container myimage
```

Then you would see `production.log` in `/a/local/host/path`.

Comment: I checked in my container not in host. I put log file same directory with source code.

Comment: @TrầnKimDự How did you check in your container? Did you do a docket exec -it mycontainer bash? (http://stackoverflow.com/a/31580097/6309)

Comment: Yes.  that's true. I run that command to go into my container's directory app.

Comment: @TrầnKimDự in that case, you need to debug your app in your container first: has it started successfully? Do you see it when you do a `ps -eaf`? Is there a right issue (no write access to write the logs), ...

Comment: My server started successfully. I'm thinking about permission too. How can I verify if a file can be written by a process ? thanks

Comment: @TrầnKimDự simply do a `ls -alrth` in the log folder, check its associated right and user: `rwxrwxr-x`? And compare that with the user running your app process (that you see with a `ps -eaf`)