# Make filebeats docker logging compatible on all platform

Tags: docker

I want to create a Filebeat container to send every docker log to elastic.
My problem is that every tutorial of Filebeat show me a Filebeat input with the path
'/var/lib/docker/containers/*/*.log'
But this path is only available on Linux system .
In Mac or windows docker logs are not stored in a file.
Is there a way to root every log to elastic without OS dependency ?

Thanks you for your time

Comment: Q: What's the "external environment" you wish your container to send log information to?  Where do you intend to run your containers? AWS?

Comment: No I want to send it to a local elastic container .

Comment: I was trying to understand a bit more about your Docker environment: where you're currently running your containers, where you ultimately want to run them, and whether the container itself is Linux or Windows.  I was leading up to "Q: Have you considered Docker volumes?"  SUGGESTIONS: 1) Open a support ticket with Elastic: https://www.elastic.co/beats/filebeat  2) Consider volumes: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54375141/421195