# Why my docker container apache service will be shut down everytime I attach my container and then exit?

Tags: docker, boot2docker

I find out an interesting behavior in my docker container,  or am I actually use it wrong.  Here is what I experience

Everytime when I attach to my container and then exit from my container, my apache service will be shutdown, what I need to do is attach back in and run the apache server again ... is that normal ??  ( my container is just a normal lamp stack )

```
docker attach 8d009c6b9a3f
root@8d009c6b9a3f# exit   // and my apache will be shut down
```

FYI, I'm using Mac and docker-machine.

Answer (score 1):

As I explained in "[difference between `docker attach` and `docker exec`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30962120/6309)", the command [`docker attach`](https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/attach/) is for attaching to the existing process.
So when you exit, you exit the existing process (the one running your Apache server).

Try instead using [`docker exec`](https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/exec/):

```
docker exec -it 8d009c6b9a3f bash
```

That will open a *separate* process (here a bash), from which you can exit without impacting the entrypoint process.

Answer (score 1):

Do not type exit because it means that you are shutting down the container.

`ctrl p + ctrl q` (hold ctrl while pressing p and q) to quit the container without exiting

see details
http://docs.docker.com/articles/basics/#running-an-interactive-shell

Answer (score -1):

You might want to use option `-d` to run the docker container as a daemon.

```
docker run -d
```

Comment: The op asks about attaching to already running container, not about running it in the first place. This does not answer the question at all.