# Docker OSX port mapping error when run: exec

Tags: macos, docker, dockerfile

If i run a container (tried both ubuntu and debian) it works fine in the background, but when i try to do docker run name -p 80:8080 i get the following error:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: invalid header field value
```

"oci runtime error: container_linux.go:247: starting container process
 caused \"exec: \\"-p\\": executable file not found in $PATH\"\n".

Here is my dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
MAINTAINER Phil Palmieri

# Install apache, PHP, and supplimentary programs. openssh-server, curl, and lynx-cur are for debugging the container.
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y upgrade && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -y install \
    apache2 php7.0 php7.0-mysql libapache2-mod-php7.0 curl lynx-cur

# Enable apache mods.
RUN a2enmod php7.0
RUN a2enmod rewrite

# Update the PHP.ini file, enable <? ?> tags and quieten logging.
RUN sed -i "s/error_reporting = .*$/error_reporting = E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE/" /etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini

# Manually set up the apache environment variables
ENV APACHE_RUN_USER www-data
ENV APACHE_RUN_GROUP www-data
ENV APACHE_LOG_DIR /var/log/apache2
ENV APACHE_LOCK_DIR /var/lock/apache2
ENV APACHE_PID_FILE /var/run/apache2.pid

# Expose apache.
EXPOSE 80

# Copy this repo into place.
ADD . /var/www/site

# Mount the volume for dev
VOLUME [".:/var/www/site"]

# Update the default apache site with the config we created.
ADD apache-config.conf /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf

# By default start up apache in the foreground, override with /bin/bash for interative.
CMD ["/usr/sbin/apache2ctl", "-D", "FOREGROUND"]
```

Comment: please paste the exact command that you are trying to run the container with.

Comment: Works: docker run -it -d abbvie/wow17:1.0

Comment: Does not work docker run -it -d abbvie/wow17:1.0 -p 8080:80

Comment: also tried docker run -it -d abbvie/wow17:1.0 -p 80:8080 (in case i messed it up)

Comment: also tried without the -d, just to try - same error

Comment: `docker run -it -d -p 80:8080 abbvie/wow17:1.0 `

Comment: Awesome! thanks, make that a reply so i can mark answered

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proper `docker run` in your case looks like this:

`docker run -i -d -p 80:8080 abbvie/wow17:1.0`

Comment: i thought you needed the it flag if you wanted to connect to it at some point

Comment: You just need `-i` if your container exits without a command.

Comment: @PhilPalmieri There's a pretty good explanation of foreground vs background in the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#/detached-vs-foreground). You may also find this answer helpful [difference between docker attach and docker exec](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30960686/difference-between-docker-attach-and-docker-exec/30962120#30962120)