# How does Docker run a command without invoking a command shell?

Tags: shell, docker, dockerfile

I'm learning about Docker at the moment, and going through the [Dockerfile reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/), specifically the [**`RUN`**](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/run) instruction. There are two forms of **`RUN`** - the *shell* form, which runs the command in a shell, and the *exec* form, which "does not invoke a command shell" (quoted from the *Note* section).

If I understood the documentation correctly, my question is - **If, and how can, Docker run a command without a shell?**

> Note that the answers to [Can a command be executed without a shell?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/203634/can-a-command-be-executed-without-a-shell)'s don't actually answer the question.

Comment: How do you think the shell itself invokes an external command once it's parsed the command line you fed it? There *has* to be an OS-level interface it can call. (Also, the pass-a-string-to-a-shell approach has major security flaws -- shell injection vulnerabilities are easily avoided if you pass arguments out-of-band, either in the environment or on other argv positions, but `system(string_to_parse)` doesn't provide a convenient way to do either).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you're asking how something can be run (specifically in the context of docker) without invoking a command shell.

The way things are run in the linux kernel are usually using [the `exec` family of system calls.](https://linux.die.net/man/3/exec)

You pass it the path to the executable you want to run and the arguments that need to be passed to it via an execl call for example.

---

This is actually what your shell (sh, bash, ksh, zsh) does under the hood anyway. You can observe this yourself if you run something like `strace -f bash -c "cat /tmp/foo"`

In the output of that command you'll see something like this:

```
execve("/bin/cat", ["cat", "/tmp/foo"], [/* 66 vars */]) = 0
```

What's really going on is that bash looks up `cat` in `$PATH`, it then finds that `cat` is actually an executable binary available at `/bin/cat`. It then simply invokes it via `execve`. and the correct arguments as you can see above.

You can trivially write a C program that does the same thing as well.
This is what such a program would look like:

```
#include<unistd.h>

int main() {

    execl("/bin/cat", "/bin/cat", "/tmp/foo", (char *)NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

Every language provides its own way of interfacing with these system calls. C does, Python does and Go, which is what's used to write Docker for the most part, does as well. A `RUN` instruction in the docker likely translates to one of these `exec` calls when you hit `docker build`. You can run an `strace -f docker build` and then `grep` for `exec` calls in the log to see how the magic happens.

---

The only difference between running something via a shell and directly is that you lose out on all the fancy stuff your shell will do for you, such as variable expansion, executable searching etc.

Comment: I was unsure about this (that's why I search for [this question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/203634/can-a-command-be-executed-without-a-shell)). You're telling me that it is possible to run a command without a shell?

Comment: @dayuloli, yes indeed it is. I'll update with an example in a bit.

Comment: After reading your answer I understand a lot more now, thank you!

Comment: Stumbling back at this question a few years later, there is one glaring mistake here: `strace -f docker build` will not actually showing the exec syscall, because the `docker` cli client does not actually run the build itself, the docker daemon does. Therefore one would have to attach an `strace` to the docker daemon's PID  before issuing the `docker build` command to actually see the exec happening.

Answer (score 1):

A program can execute another program without a shell; you just create a new process and load an executable onto it, so you don't need the shell for that. The shell is needed for a user to start a program because it is the user interface to the system. Also, a program is not able to run a built-in command like cd or rm without a shell because there's no executable to be found (there are alternative ways, thought, but not as simple).

Comment: And you'd need the shell to run a script because the interpreter is contained in it.

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer, it clarified so much for me. So here, when I am building my Docker image, if I use the shell form of `RUN`, it will spawn a new shell, let the shell interpret the command, and then run the interpreted command. If I use the *exec* form, the current process that is running `docker run` will create a new process, passing the executable to it.

Comment: Exactly. Thus running something without a shell is more lightweight, but with a few less capabilities. If the command you want to run is an executable (binary, not a script), and you don't need to translate something in the command line arguments (like environment variables) then the shell would be just a burden.

Answer (score 0):

In very general - `docker run` will start container with its default process, when docker exec allow you to run any process you want inside the container.

For example, running microsoft/iis container by `docker run microsoft/iis`will run default process, which is powershell.

But you can run cmd by running `docker exec -i my_container cmd`

[See this answer for more details.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30960686/difference-between-docker-attach-and-docker-exec)