# How hello world container is printing the welcome text?

Tags: linux, docker, dockerfile, containers, docker-container

I have read somewhere that the hello-world docker image is from scratch so it doesn't have a shell then how it is executing the `hello` executable file ? Don't we need a shell to execute a file ?

Comment: Commands are run in the linux kernel usually using [exec family of functions](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exec.3.html) so you don't need a shell. Similar question [How does Docker run a command without invoking a command shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42257450/8482479)

Comment: `Don't we need a shell to execute a file ?` - "shell", by itself, is a executable file. You don't need shell to execute the file. Just execute it instead of the shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the docker `CMD` is designed to run executable.

**CMD**

The CMD instruction has three forms:

```
CMD ["executable","param1","param2"] (exec form, this is the preferred form)
CMD ["param1","param2"] (as default parameters to ENTRYPOINT)
CMD command param1 param2 (shell form)
```

> There can only be one CMD instruction in a Dockerfile. If you list
>   more than one CMD then only the last CMD will take effect.
>
> **The main purpose of a CMD is to provide defaults for an executing
>   container.** These defaults can include an executable, or they can omit
>   the executable, in which case you must specify an ENTRYPOINT
>   instruction as well.

So CMD and entrypoint run executable you do not need shell. you will get same response if you run

```
docker run -it --entrypoint ./hello --rm hello-world
docker run -it --rm hello-world
```