# What is Docker attach?

Tags: docker

I am very new to Docker and I have been able to understand 4 things

- Dockerfile
- Docker image
- Docker container
- docker-compose

along with some basic commands like `docker run`, `docker log`, etc.

Now, I came across this command `docker attach` with a description here

> Use docker attach to attach to a running container using the container’s ID or name, either to view its ongoing output or to control it interactively. You can attach to the same contained process multiple times simultaneously, screen sharing style, or quickly view the progress of your detached process.

I have no idea what do they mean when they say we can attach if we want to view a container's `ongoing activity or output?` If I have a Container for a console application and I simply do `docker run` on it then I can see the output right there in the console window.

What could be a few benefits of the `docker attach` command?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

When containers are run with the interactive option, you can connect to the container and enter commands as if you are on the terminal:

```
$ docker run -itd --name busybox busybox
dcaecf3335f9142e8c70a2ae05a386395b49d610be345b3a12d2961fccab1478

$ docker attach busybox
/ # echo hello world
hello world
```

The `attach` option also allows multiple connections to view the same container and see what each is typing.

Lastly, while connected to a container with the tty option (`-t`), you can type <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>P</kbd> <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>Q</kbd> to detach from that container and leave it running in the background. You can then attach to that container again in the future.

Comment: **The attach option also allows multiple connections to view the same container and see what each is typing.** - Could you please explain what does this mean in detail.

Comment: @Underoos multiple command prompts can attach to the same container simultaneously.

Comment: `and see what each is typing`. Do that mean once the command is executed, it will show up in `history` output on all command prompts?

Comment: @Underoos have you tried running the commands above? `busybox` is a rather small base image to test with.

Comment: For the audience about the `The attach option also allows multiple connections to view the same container and see what each is typing` sentence - see the following explanation at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30960686/difference-between-docker-attach-and-docker-exec/77997774#77997774

Answer (score 13):

> What is Docker attach?

Allows one terminal to attach a running container. It allows you to connect to process' STDIO in another terminal.

What's the benefit?

[Docs:](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/attach/)

> This allows you to view its ongoing output or to control it
>   interactively, as though the commands were running directly in your
>   terminal.

Here's a demo of attach:

[image]

Comment: It's good to provide some new information in answers but I think your answer doesn't provide any valuable information regarding what was asked in the question. The question was about docker attach, OP knew about other commands.

Comment: OP asked about benefits of docker attach, I answered that by explaining the benefit and added in a demo - this is valuable info IMO. As for the other concepts, I misread the opening sentence and have edited the answer.

Comment: Not really clear how it's better than the logs in that case.

Answer (score 5):

Docker attach command is used to attach our terminal to a running container to control I/O operations.