# When to use `--attach` with `docker container run`?

Tags: docker

I found [that](https://morioh.com/p/26b2cc2c678a) -

> By default, when no option is provided to the `docker run` command,
>   the root process is started in the foreground. This means that the
>   standard input, output, and error from the root process are attached
>   to the terminal session.

So, what is the difference between `$ docker container run -ait ubuntu` **&** `$ docker container run -it ubuntu`?

When to use `--attach` with `docker container run`?

Comment: Did you read the description in https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/? What difference have you observed in use?

Comment: I read https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/container_run/ and also the difference between attach and exec. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30960686/difference-between-docker-attach-and-docker-exec but could not understand in this context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[If you do not specify -a then Docker will attach to both stdout and stderr when running in foreground mode.](https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/4118e0c9eebda2412a09ae66e90c34b85fae3275/runconfig/opts/parse.go#L267) You can use `--attach` option to attach to specific streams instead.

```
-a=[]           : Attach to `STDIN`, `STDOUT` and/or `STDERR`
```

```
docker run -a stdin -a stdout -i -t ubuntu /bin/bash
```

Comment: https://github.com/docker/cli/blob/f5280d60ee0ce918a972fac35d0775aaba81a2a7/man/docker-run.1.md