# How do get GoCD server to run persistently in Docker to run in a VM?

Tags: ubuntu, docker, virtualbox, go-cd

I am trying to run GoCD server in Docker in a VM. To test the setup I created an Ubuntu 14.04 server in VirtualBox, installed Docker, and then following instructions from

https://github.com/gocd/gocd-docker & https://hub.docker.com/r/gocd/gocd-server/ I ran:
`docker run -tiP gocd/gocd-server`

This works, but the problem is that if I close the terminal (which I'll have to do in production because I cannot keep an SSH terminal open indefinitely) the server dies. I was able to get the port this server was running on by opening another terminal to the VM and running docker PS. I was able to access that one from my browser. Of course I need a solution that allows me to close the terminal.

So I tried it again (in a fresh VM), hit Ctrl+C, waited for it to shut down, then ran:

`docker rename randomDockerName gocd-server`

and then

`docker start gocd-server`
`docker ps`

I then see something like

`randomLetters        gocd/gocd-server    "/sbin/my_init"     25 minutes ago      Up 10 minutes       0.0.0.0:32773->8153/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32772->8154/tcp  gocd-server`

So I point my chrome on my Ubuntu 14.04 host machine to ipaddress:32773 and I get nothing. Now when the docker image was running with docker run this worked just fine, so why isn't this working with docker start? I can't use run again because that creates a new docker image and I have to keep the terminal open to keep the server running.

So my question is, how do I run GoCD in Docker on a VM without having to stay logged in to that VM?

Also, the Ubuntu VM is configured in VirtualBox with both a NAT and a Bridged network card.

Comment: Well I feel silly. All I had to do was Ctrl+p + Ctrl+q as per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19688314/how-do-you-attach-and-detach-from-dockers-process

Comment: Did you look at `docker run --restart=always` ? See the doc https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/run/

Answer (score 2):

If your application really requires to have an open terminal, you can install [`screen`](http://www.rackaid.com/blog/linux-screen-tutorial-and-how-to/). With that tool you could *detach* from a that process before you close your ssh connection. Next time you re-connect you could attach back to that process to get back the terminal.

An other possibility would be to run your container in background with the `-d` flag:

```
docker run -d -P gocd/gocd-server
```