# How to attach visual studio 2015 debugger to previously deployed asp.net core docker container

Tags: debugging, docker, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, remote-debugging

I have used the docker support extension for visual studio 2015 and it works great. I am able to launch and debug asp.net core app from visual studio.

I would like to know if there is a way to reattach the visual studio debugger to the docker container?

The container is already running and has the clrdbg tool installed.

I have tried wrapping the docker exec in a powershell to run the clrdbg and setting the project executable to the PowerShell. I am not sure this is even close to the correct method. I just update the command to the correct containerid and start debug from VS. the powershell starts but I can't hit a break point.

```
docker exec -i 89595163e6bd /clrdbg/clrdbg --interpreter=mi
```

Docker Version:

```
 Version:      1.12.0
 API version:  1.24
 Go version:   go1.6.3
 Git commit:   8eab29e
 Built:        Thu Jul 28 21:04:48 2016
 OS/Arch:      windows/amd64
 Experimental: true
```

Dotnet version:

```
1.0.0-preview2-003121
```

Comment: I just know that to detach from the container you should use Ctrl+p + Ctrl+q, no information about the VS attach to process: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19688314/how-do-you-attach-and-detach-from-dockers-process

Answer (score -1):

Please try the steps mentioned on the below link.

https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/issues/162

I also tried copying the 100+ files from other machine and at least the application was working on Docker. Yet to make it working with debugger.

Comment: Don't use answers to request more information. If you need more info, ask using a comment. Additionally, it is better to include the bulk of the answer in your answer and use the link as a method of further reference. - [From review](http://stackoverflow.com/review)