# Possible to create a script that enters/exits a docker container?

Tags: python, bash, docker, automation

From [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19688314/how-do-you-attach-and-detach-from-dockers-process) I found out that I can detach from a docker container with the sequence <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>q</kbd>.

I was wondering, is it possible to create a single bash (or python, or whatever) script that enters a docker container, runs a few commands, then uses the escape sequence to exit the container? I think it may not be possible, but please confirm/deny this!

Answer (score 1):

`docker exec --detach` (or `-d`) should run commands without attaching.

Comment: ah of course, much simpler to never attach in the first place. Thanks I should have remembered this!

Comment: You're welcome! I take it this is the accepted answer?

Comment: Yup, it was so quick that it wants me to wait another 5 mins to accept ;)