# Cannot detach from Docker console with Java process on it

Tags: java, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, minecraft

I'm not able to detach from a Docker container after I attached to it.

Dockerfile to define the container:

```
FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk16:debian
WORKDIR /app
STOPSIGNAL SIGTERM
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl && apt clean
CMD curl -so server.jar https://ci.tivy.ca/job/Airplane-1.17/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/launcher-airplane.jar && java -jar server.jar
```

Build the container with: `docker build -t minecraft .`

docker-compose file:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  mc:
    container_name: mc
    ports:
      - 25565:25565
    image: minecraft
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: /root/mc
        target: /app
```

Start the container with: `docker-compose up mc`

I tryed to attach to console with `docker attach mc`, it works. But I'm not unable to detach from screen. Ctrl+C not work. Ctrl+P and Ctrl+Q not work. Writing `stop` (command that will stop the java process) not working

I tryed to attach with `docker attach --detach-keys="ctrl-d" mc` but is not working

**Java process never ends**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you attach and detach from Docker's process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19688314/how-do-you-attach-and-detach-from-dockers-process)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found fix myself. Need to insert stdin_open and ttyin docker-compose file. New docker-compose.yml:

```
 version: "3.7"
 services:
  mc:
    container_name: mc
    ports:
      - 25565:25565
    image: minecraft
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: /root/mc
        target: /app
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
```

Will set this answer as solution in two days because of stackoverflow rules